# Getting a file with lines and turning them into a dictionary with lists

Tags: python

my problem is that I want to read a file with multiple lines e.g.:

```
be:was, were
I:you
Tom
```

Now I want to turn the first element (before the ':') into the key of the dict and everything what comes after the ':' into a list. Every list entry is separated with ','

So it should look like this:

```
words_dict = {"be" : ["was", "were"], "I" : ["you"], "Tom" : []}
```

I came up with something like this:

```
with open(words, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.strip().split(':')
```

I don't know if this is the right approach and what to do next.

Comment: You are on the right lines, but check the `maxsplit` option on `split`. I would first split on `:` with maxsplit set to 1; the first part is your dictionary key, and then the second part might be best split using `re.split` using a delimiter such as `',\s*'` (comma followed by any amount of whitespace) to give a list which is the dictionary value.

Comment: And you will need to handle lack of `:` in the line as a special case, where `line.split(':', 1)` returns a one-element instead of two-element list.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something along the lines of

```py
with open(words, 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines(1024):
        split = line.removesuffix('\n').split(':', maxsplit=1)

        if len(split) == 2:
            vals = [val.strip() for val in split[1].split(',')]
        else: # : not found in line
            vals = []

        d[split[0]] = vals
```

If you can clean up the data to always guarantee there's a `:` after the key, the loop can be simplified greatly;

```py
with open(words, 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines(1024):
        key, value = line.removesuffix('\n').split(':', maxsplit=1)
        d[key] = [val.strip() for val in value.split(',')]
```

Comment: if you could clean up the data to always have `:` (e.g. `Tom:`), you could clean up this code a bit by removing the necessity for a `if len(split) != 2` check, and you could just do `key, value = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)`

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Whether to read the whole file in at once is possibly debatable, depending on memory requirements. You could use a list comprehension for `vals` but it's not important.

Comment: made the list comprehension improvement & added the improved case to my answer, and yes @alani you're right, memory could perhaps be a problem.

Comment: That looks fine. One way to deal with occasional lines without any colon is to catch any `ValueError` where you unpack the `line.split(...)` output.

Comment: Improved my code to fix the possible memory issue in the case of a very large file.

Answer (score 0):

You should first split the line with `':'` to get the keys and the rest of the string (if it has) which are going to be values later. Then split the values with `','` and filter them if they are not empty after stripping.

Try this one:

```py
d = {}
with open(words) as f:
    for line in f:
        key, *values = line.strip().split(':', maxsplit=1)
        values = ''.join(values)
        values = [w for word in values.split(',') if (w := word.strip())]
        d[key] = values
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'be': ['was', 'were'], 'I': ['you'], 'Tom': []}
```

Note that this works because: first, "join" method will not raise exception for empty iterables, second, "split" also doesn't complain with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

A short solution:

```
data = {}
with open('words.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        key, *value = line.strip().split(':')
        data[key] = list(filter(None, [i.strip() for i in ','.join(value).split(',')]))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'be': ['was', 'were'], 'I': ['you'], 'Tom': []}
```

Comment: You are not doing the split on commas that is required.

Comment: "was" and "were" should be 2 separate items inside the list

Comment: @pigeonburger Emm not really, there is an extra space before the `' were'` . (Also don't forget to update the output)

Comment: NOW i fixed it. woohoo

Comment: @pigeonburger I think you should check it one more time

Comment: Could somebody explain what exactly is going on in the 4th and 5th line (key, *value...)

Comment: @Frezoki The first item in `line.strip().split(':')` is assigned to `key`, then `value` is a list containing everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
with open(words, 'r') as file:
    words = {(l:=s.rstrip('\n').split(':'))[0]:l[1].split(', ') if len(l)>1 else []
             for s in file}
```

Comment: There is an extra `'\n'` in the list's items.

Comment: You're right @SorousH I just did it on top of my head, forgot to strip ;)

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner:

```
{ p[0]: p[2].split(' ') for line in open('words.txt') if (p := line.strip().partition(':')) }
```

Seems to give the desired result:

```
{'be': ['was,', 'were'], 'I': ['you'], 'Tom': ['']}
```